# Searching a string and replacing another string above the searched string

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file with the lines below

```
123
456
123
789
abc
efg
xyz
```

I need to search with `abc` and replace immediate above `123` with `111`.  This is the requirement, `abc` is only one occurrence in the file but `123` can be multiple occurrences and 123 can be at any position above `abc`.
Please help me.

I have tried with below sed command

```
sed -i.bak "/abc/!{x;1!p;d;};x;s/123/1111" filename
```

With the above command, it is only replacing `123`, if `123` is just above `abc`, if `123` is 2 lines above `abc` then replace is failing.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than on way to do it. Here's one:

```
sed -i.bak '1{h;d;};/123/{x;p;d;};/abc/{x;s/123/111/;p;d;};H;${x;p;};d' filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is working, but when I used variable for "abc"
variable substitution is failing<br>
var=abc
sed -i.bak '1{h;d;};/123/{x;p;d;};/${var}/{x;s/123/111/;p;d;};H;${x;p;};d' filename

Comment: @kiranpaila: Try `sed "...$var..."` (Note the double quotes and lack of parentheses.)

Comment: How to use the below command to just search for above 5 lines for replace sed -i.bak '1{h;d;};/123/{x;p;d;};/abc/{x;s/123/111/;p;d;};H;${x;p;};d' filename
Need to check only few previous lines for replacing instead of all the previous lines

Answer (score 0):

`ed` comes in handy for complex editing of files in scripts:

```
ed -s file <<EOF
/^abc$/;?^123$?;.c
111
.
w
EOF
```

This: Sets the current line to the first one matching `abc` (`/^abc$/;`). Then changes the first line *before* that point that matches `123` to `111` (`?XXX?` searches backwards for a matching regular expression, and `?^123$?;.` selects that single line for `c` to **c**hange) and finally saves the modified file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ez 's/(.*)(\n123.*\nabc)/\1\n111\2/' file
```

This slurps the file into memory and inserts `111` in front of the last occurrence of `123` before `abc`.

A less memory intensive solution:

```
sed -E '/^123$/{:a;N;/\n123$/{h;s///p;g;s/.*\n//;ba};/\nabc$/!ba;s/^/111\n/}' file
```

This gathers up lines following a line containing `123`. If another line containing `123` is encountered it offloads all lines before it and begins gathering lines again. If it finds a line containing `abc` it inserts `111` at the front of the lines gathered so far.

Another alternative:

```
sed '/abc/{x;/./{s/^/111\n/p;z};x;b};/123/{x;/./p;x;h;$!d;b};x;/./{x;H;$!d};x' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case where you keep track of your previous line and change stuff depeinding on conditions satisfying the current line. Genearlly, an awk program looks like this:

```
awk '(FNR==1){prev=$0; next}
     (condition_on_$0) { action_on_prev }
     { print prev; prev = $0 }
     END { print $0 }'
```

So in the case of the OP, this would read:

```
awk '(FNR==1){prev=$0; next}
     $0 == "abc" { if (prev == "123") prev = "111" }
     { print prev; prev = $0 }
     END { print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tac file | awk 'f && sub(/123/,"111"){f=0} /abc/{f=1} 1' | tac
123
456
111
789
abc
efg
xyz
```